# Numbers containing e in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

In ArcGIS when I try to calculate some raster values or statistics, sometimes I get values that contain e, for example: 1.4e6.

What does e mean, and how is it interpreted in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 8):

The `e` is seen as the **base** number (which would be 10) with the **exponent** (to the power) of 6 in your case.

In other words:

```
1.4e6 = 1.4 x 10^6 = 1,400,000
```

Comment: Commonly known as [E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Comment: @jpmc26 - Awesome, thanks for adding that link!